# see if content element is a reference or not

Tags: php, typo3

Hi I need to find out if an content element is a reference or not.

I tried to see if $this->destPointer was set but then I realized that this was set for all elements...

I cant find where the references are saved in the database either.

Someone got any idea?

Comment: @Pekka destPointer is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References are saved in the "pages" table, column "tx_templavoila_flex" (XML format).

Check the current page id against the content elements' pid and then you know whether it's a reference.

```
if($this->cObj->data['pid'] != $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id) {
    //reference
}
else {
    //not a reference
}
```